# Uncaught PDO Exception with message syntax error or access violation:1064

Tags: php, pdo

here is my dboperations.php snippet:

```
class DB{
    private $host="localhost";
private $db_name="abcd";
private $db_user="root";
private $db_pass="";

public function __construct(){
    if(!isset($this->db)){
        try{
            $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db_name,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->db=$conn;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die("Failed to connect with MySQL: ".$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public function getRows($table,$conditions=array()){
    $sql='SELECT ';
    $sql.=array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
    $sql.=' FROM '.$table;
    if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
        $sql.=' WHERE ';
        $i=0;
        foreach($conditions['where'] as $key=>$value){
            $pre=($i>0)?' AND ':'';
            $sql.=$pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by']; 
    }

    if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit']; 
    }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit']; 
    }

    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    if(array_key_exists("return_type",$conditions) && $conditions['return_type'] != 'all'){
        switch($conditions['return_type']){
            case 'count':
                $data = $query->rowCount();
                break;
            case 'single':
                $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;
            default:
                $data = '';
        }
    }else{
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            $data = $query->fetchAll();
        }
    }
    return !empty($data)?$data:false;
    }
}
```

and here is my index.php snippet:

```
<?php
    include 'DBOperations.php';
                $db=new DB();
                $members=$db->getRows('members',array('where'=>array('team_id'=>$_SESSION['team_id']),'order_by'=>'user_id DESC'));
                if(!empty($members)){
                    $count=0;
                    foreach($members as $member){
                        $user_id=$member['user_id'];
                        $user=$db->getRows('users',array('where'=>array('index'=>$user_id)));?>
```

I am getting the error mentioned in the question title while running the above code.I get the error on the last line of index.php.Please let me know how to resolve this problem.As you can see I have two tables in my database:users and members.members has 3 columns:index,user_id,team_id.users has several columns:index,first_name,last_name,email,phone,etc.why am I getting this error.Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Echo/log your query after you build it, the answer should be there.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like looking at the query string you're building?

Comment: yes i did some debugging and directly used the query string in index.php instead of generating it..but it showed the same error.

Comment: Post your query string. Your sql syntax is wrong there, so you need to look at how to fix the syntax.